# chart x-axis order date ascending error

Tags: c#, charts

I have a chart with x axis(date:year) and y-axis (percents).

I have 4 series which are Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4.
(Q: quarter of year)

I want to sort my colums from 2013 to 2004.
like this

2013-Q1,
2012-Q4,
2012-Q3,
2012-Q2,
2012-Q1,
2011-Q4,
2011-Q3,
2011-Q2,
2011-Q1,
etc..

How can I do this?

(note: I am sending datas one by one from 2013-Q1 to 2004-Q4 but it seems mixed.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the mschart, dundas, zedgraph ?? Do you mean that you need 4 different graphs in the chart ? Please elaborate your question. Add some code...

Comment: can you look at this subject. I had explained that before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846450/i-have-an-error-about-chart-columns-order